# How to generate PDF by chromium in AWS lambda, node.js v18

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, puppeteer, chromium

I am trying to generate PDF by [@sparticuz/chromium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sparticuz/chromium) using AWS lambda, node.js v18, layer and architecture: x86_64.

I get the error:

> Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module
> '@sparticuz/chromium'

Layer:

```
{
  "name": "chrome_layer",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sparticuz/chromium": "108.0.1",
    "puppeteer-core": "18.0.5"
  }
}
```

Code:

```
const chromium = require('@sparticuz/chromium')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core')

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case I was trying to deploy the Lambda with AWS CDK, without a separate layer.

When you create the `NodejsFunction`, inside `NodejsFunctionProps`, pass two things:

1. the `package-lock.json` file:

   ```
   depsLockFilePath: 'src/your-lambda-path/package-lock.json',
   ```
2. Make sure the `@sparticuz/chromium` module won't be bundled as a single file, but rather passed as is in `node_modules` folder:

   ```
   bundling.nodeModules: [
       '@sparticuz/chromium',
   ],
   ```

This way the binary for Chromium will be installed.